# Catching local mails

Tags: magento2, mail

Hey I would like to be able to catch mails from my local Magento 2 environnement.
Anyone got an idea on this ?
I've seen some extension but I would be surprised if we cannot execute that without any extension.
Anyway, if you could share with me what are your method to catch mail from your M2 local environnement, that would be really helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Send emails From Local Enviorment You need to configure SMTP

there are serval extension available of Github that you can use easily yo configure SMTP with you Gmail Account

one of them is https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp

download this extension install it and then configure it from Gmail

please read user guide to enable from GMail Side as well

Thank You